# Do two points have the same neighborhoods if all their neighborhoods intersect?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, discrete-mathematics

Consider a topological space $(M,\mathscr{M})$ and $p,q\in M$. We suppose that for any two neighborhoods $N_p$ and $N_q$ we have that
$$\tag{1}
N_p\cap N_q\ne\emptyset
$$
But since this includes the smallest open sets that contain $q$ and $p$, does the condition in eq. $(1)$ not imply that any neighborhood of one of the two points is also a neighborhood of the other point? And this would imply that for $4$ distinct neighborhoods, we would also have
$(N_p^{(1)}\cap N_q^{(1)})\cap(N_p^{(2)}\cap N_q^{(2)})\ne\emptyset$?

Edit: the reason for the question is that I want to show that
$$
F=\{S\subseteq M|\exists N_p\exists N_q \text{ such that } N_p\cap N_q\subseteq S\}
$$
is a filter on $M$. Thus I need to show that I can find $4$ neighborhoods such that $(N_p^{(1)}\cap N_q^{(1)})\cap(N_p^{(2)}\cap N_q^{(2)})$ is in $F$, which means that $(N_p^{(1)}\cap N_q^{(1)})$ should be a neighborhood of $p$ and that $(N_p^{(2)}\cap N_q^{(2)})$ should be a neighborhood of $q$.

Comment: You do not need to show that $N_p^{(1)}\cap N_q^{(1)}$ is a neighborhood of $p$. That intersection is equal to $\bigl(N_p^{(1)}\cap N_p^{(2)} \bigr)\cap\bigl( N_q^{(1)}\cap N_q^{(2)}\bigr)$, so you just need $N_p^{(1)}\cap N_p^{(2)}$ to be a neighborhood of $p$ and $N_q^{(1)}\cap N_q^{(2)}$ to be a neighborhood of $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the title in your question is "no" for general topological spaces. For example, consider $M=\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology (a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is open if and only if it is empty, or its complement is finite). Then any two nonempty open sets intersect, but given any points $p\neq q$, there exist neighborhoods $U_p$ and $U_q$ such that $p\in U_p$ and $q\notin U_p$, and $q\in U_q$ but $p\notin U_q$.

This kind of problem is related to the notion of [separation axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom), which are properties of topological spaces.

One problem with your thinking is the notion of "smallest open set". Even in "nice" spaces like the real numbers with the usual topology, there is no "smallest open set" containing any given point.

A topological space in which for any two points $p\neq q$ there exists an open set containing one but not the other is called a $T_0$ space; the smallest example is the [Sierpinski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), which is the example given by Przemyslaw Scherwentke.

A topological space in which for any two points $p\neq q$ there exist open sets $U_p$ and $U_q$ such that $p\in U_p$, $q\in U_q$, and $U_p\cap U_q=\varnothing$ is called a $T_2$ or Hausdorff space.

The space I give above is called a $T_1$-space.

---

I'm not sure what you are trying to argue in your edit. The question is whether
$$\mathcal{F} = \{S\subseteq M\mid \text{there are nbds }N_p\text{ of }p\text{ and }N_q\text{ of }q\text{ such that }N_p\cap N_q\subseteq S\}$$
is a filter on $M$. That requires that it be nonempty, upward closed (if $S\in\mathcal{F}$ and $S\subseteq T$, then $T\in\mathcal{F}$, and closed under intersections, so that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are both in $\mathcal{F}$, then $S_1\cap S_2$ lies in $\mathcal{F}$.

That it is nonempty follows because $M$ itself lies in $\mathcal{F}$, witnessed by taking $N_p=N_q=M$.

If $S$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ and $S\subseteq T$, then we know there are neighborhoods $N_p$ of $p$ and $N_q$ of $q$ such that $N_p\cap N_q\subseteq S$, and hence $N_p\cap N_q\subseteq T$, so the same neighborhoods that witness the fact that $S$ lies in $\mathcal{F}$ also witness the fact that $T$ lies in $\mathcal{F}$.

Now assume that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are both in $\mathcal{F}$. Then there are neighborhoods $N_p,U_p$ of $p$, and $N_q,U_q$ of $q$, such that $N_p\cap N_q\subseteq S_1$ and $U_p\cap U_q\subseteq S_2$.

Now, we know that there is a neighborhood $O_p$ of $p$ such that $p\in O_p\subseteq N_p\cap U_p$, and there is a neighborhood $O_q$ of $q$ such that $q\in O_q\subseteq N_q\cap U_q$. Then
$$O_p\cap O_q\subseteq (N_p\cap U_p)\cap(N_q\cap U_q) = (N_p\cap N_q)\cap(U_p\cap U_q)\subseteq S_1\cap S_2,$$
so it follows that $S_1\cap S_2\in\mathcal{F}$. Thus, $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter.

You will note that I did not need to find neighborhoods as you claim you needed to find: you don't need the intersections to lie in the (purported) filter.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Could you please see my edit?

Comment: @Hydrogen: I think you are confused about what you need to prove. I've added a proof that what you describe is a filter.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let us consider $M=\{p,q\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, \{p\}, \{p,q\}\}$. Then $\{p\}\cap\{p,q\}=\{p\}$, but $\{p\}$ is not a neighbourhood of $q$.